# Media query not responding on pc

Tags: html, css, angular, media-queries

I was using media query and it was working, but now it just stopped working, but if I use the developer tool of the browser the media query works well
[image]

[image]

Here is my media query code, but I dont think that that is the error

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px) and (max-device-width: 760px) {
    .conainerInp {
        display: block !important;
    }
    .contInputs,
    .contInputs3 {
        flex: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .last {
        margin-bottom: 60px;
    }
    .contenido {
        display: flex !important;
        flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    }
    .contenedoresGen {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
     ::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-content-container {
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
     ::ng-deep.mat-horizontal-stepper-content {
        overflow: auto !important;
    }
     ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-container {
        overflow-x: auto !important;
    }
}
```

the screen was at a measure less thant the indicated in the media query
[image]

Comment: your website looks awsome

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following `meta` to your `HTML` in the `head` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: This is the 100% correct answer, you have initialize the viewport first!

Comment: I already have it declared :(

Comment: You can also change your logic from `max-width` to `min-width` and it will work for you, (the problem of `viewport` is only for `max-width`)

Comment: It seems to be the problem, but do you know how can I change that logic or how i can fix that of max width?

Comment: For example if your code is `div { display: block' } @media only screen and (max-width: 760px) { div { display: none; } }` So you have to write in reverse like this: `div { display: none; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) { div { display: block; } }`

Comment: omg thats a lot of work :0, but thanks I'll do it, have any idea of why it just stopped working? :\

Comment: If what I wrote works for you, then you must have a problem with the meta tag you included in my answer, because that's exactly what it came to solve

Comment: I found the error, it was because of the
and (max-device-width: 760px)

Comment: it is working on devices but it is not working on browser, have an idea of how can i use both??

Comment: As I said, the `meta` tag solves the problem for a browser, the device will not have any problem even without this tag, check that it is written correctly on your device

Answer (score 0):

I foun out the problem, it was my conditions, it neaded that the sceen be at 760px also the devie at the same time, I already had the meta tag before asking this, the solution was removing

```
and (max-device-width: 760px)
```

and it still working on movile because of the meta tag